# C# HttpWebRequest times out after two server 500 errors

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

After I make two C# HttpWebRequests that throw an exception because of "(500) Internal Server Error 500", the third attempt throws a time out exception. Why doesn't it throw another (500) Internal Server Error exception?

When I restart my application, it throws two 500 errors and then starts timing out again.

**This is my code:**

```
GetPages GetPages = new GetPages();
string test = GetPages.GetPage(); /* Exception: (500) Internal Server Error */
GetPages.Dispose();

GetPages GetPages = new GetPages();
string test = GetPages.GetPage();  /* Exception: (500) Internal Server Error */
GetPages.Dispose();

GetPages GetPages = new GetPages();
string test = GetPages.GetPage();  /* Exception: time out, why? */
GetPages.Dispose();
```

**This is GetPages class and GetPage method:**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class GetPages
    {
        public string GetPage()
        {
            this.httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myurl");

            try
            {
                StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder(100);
                postData.Append("test=test");
                byte[] dataArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

                httpRequest.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
                httpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
                httpRequest.Proxy = null;
                httpRequest.Method = "POST";
                httpRequest.Timeout = 10;
                httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                httpRequest.ContentLength = dataArray.Length;

                using (this.requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length);
                    requestStream.Flush();
                    requestStream.Close();

                    this.webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

                    Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader responseReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    String responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();


                    MessageBox.Show(responseString);
                    return responseString;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                return "FAIL";
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            System.GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks you all for helping out. I have not been able to solve the issue.

The dispose method is gone now.

I have made *HttpWebRequest httpRequest, HttpWebResponse webResponse and Stream requestStream* local and am using the following using statements:

```
using (webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader responseReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

**Another update**

This is the entire GetPage method now:

```
public string GetPage()
{
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest;
    HttpWebResponse webResponse;
    Stream requestStream;

    try
    {
        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder(100);
        postData.Append("test=test");
        byte[] dataArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

        httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myurl");

        httpRequest.Proxy = null;
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.Timeout = 10;
        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        httpRequest.ContentLength = dataArray.Length;

        using (requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            /* this is never reached when the time out exception starts 
            so the error seems to be related to too many GetRequestStreams */

            requestStream.Write(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length);

            webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

            /* this is never reached when the 500 server error occurs */

            String responseString = "";
            using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader responseReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                    return responseString;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "FAIL";
    }

    return "...";
}
```

** SOLVED!! **
httpRequest was not getting abort()'ed. In the catch() block I have added httpRequest.abort(), now it works correctly.

Comment: That Dispose method is the WORST I have ever seen

Comment: So having made those changes, what behaviour are you seeing? Exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, is exacly the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I *suspect* this is the problem:

```
this.webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
String responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
```

You're not disposing of any of these disposable objects. That means the connection to the web server will be maintained until finalization, so the connection pool (of two connections per server) won't allow any other requests.

I suggest that:

- You move the `GetResponse` call out of the using statement for the request stream
- You remove the explicit calls to `Flush` and `Close` for the request stream (disposing of it is good enough)
- You make `webResponse` and `webRequest` local variables instead of instance variables unless you *really* need them later, in which case you should dispose of them in your `Dispose` method.
- You use `using` statements for the `WebResponse`, `Stream`, and `StreamReader`. (The last isn't strictly necessary, as disposing of the stream is good enough.)
- You make `GetPages` not implement `IDisposable` unless you really need it to.

Comment: You dont think it is his Dispose method?  :)

Comment: Hi Jon, I have done all that you said, but could not solve the issue yet. Can you take a look at my update in the first post?

Comment: @koen: Hmm... that surprises me. It's possible that because an exception is being thrown, it's not getting to dispose of the response. You could potentially catch WebException and dispose of the response in there... but if you actually have to do that, it's pretty horrible :(

Comment: @jon: Can you take a look at the entire method? (I have added another update to the first post)

Comment: @koen: I hadn't spotted that you'd turned keep-alive off. Curiouser and curiouser. I'm afraid I don't have time to try to reproduce it at the moment :(

Comment: @jon: I had to manually abort the httpRequest with the Abort() method in the catch block. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: @koen: Ick. That's very strange :(

Comment: Moving `GetResponse` out of the using statement fixed my issue.

Answer (score 8):

HTTP protocol defines that only two connection can be made at the same time to the same server. Close the `responseStream` after successful or unsuccessful reading.

Comment: I have now wrapped the responseStream in a using statement (see update in the first post). Is that enough?

Comment: Yes, that I think is where the connection gets loose and not closed.

Comment: Weird, I put the responseStream to using block, still timing out.