# HttpWebRequest times out

Tags: c#, timeout, httpwebrequest

I have read the following 2 articles and have tried implementing the same.

My code is this and the time out occurs here

```
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
wr.Method = "POST";
wr.KeepAlive = false;
wr.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

wr.Proxy = null;
wr.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 5000;
Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream(); // -> Time out error occurs here
```

[Article I read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827030/httpwebrequest-times-out-on-second-call)

```
My code using that as a sample
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
wr.Method = "POST";
wr.KeepAlive = false;
wr.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

wr.Timeout = 5000;
wr.Proxy = null;

wr.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 5000;
wr.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 5000;

Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream(); //-->Time out error
```

Any clues would be helpful. At times I can get 1 request through and all other request fail or everything fails. Am posting to a HTTPS site. No issues when running with Fiddler

UPDATE 1:
I tried following zbugs ideas but that resulted in same issue. the first request goes through the subsequent ones fail.  I am closing all response streams as well as calling abort on my request object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set this.

```
const int maxIdleTimeout = 5000;
ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = maxIdleTimeout;
```

If you have more than one client making the request at any given time,

```
const int maxConnections = 100; //or more/less
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = maxConnections;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.maxservicepointidletime.aspx

Comment: would i have to do something like this?
            wr.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 5000;
            wr.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 5000;
            ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 5000;
            Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();

as that resulted in same time out exception

Comment: no.  ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime etc.. and you do have to dispose the wr object and the stream after you are done.

Comment: Yes i have the close and dispose method as well as wr.Abort()

Comment: all you need to do is try that before making the entering that method or creating the wr object.   Set the ServicePointManager values.

Answer (score 1):

You should release all resources that implement `IDisposable`. Not releasing them can cause the kind of issue you're experimenting.

Here you have an example that is not exaclty your code but it will help you to undertand what I mean

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On one of my request call, I had failed to call

```
Request.Abort()
```

That seems to have solved my issue along with suggestion from zbugs